# I wired up a z 80 using telephone wire and put a jump to 0000 0000 0000 0000

Tags: z80

I put 1100 0011   0000 0000   0000 0000 in the 2764 eprom --- this is supposed to test the z80 -- I have a 555 timer running at 500 khz. Can this small program work with the z80 ? I looked at the address pins on a m465 oscilloscope. The address shows highs up to 0100 0000. I think it should only count to 0000 0000   0000 0011. Can the z80 be tested? The Santa Clara Valley also made the lm1871 radio control chip that could not show a high or a low without completing the entire rc loop.

Comment: You might get a better response over at [chiphacker](http://chiphacker.com/).

Comment: Who is voting to close - this is programming related, just not something you see very often.

Comment: @slugster, this is more EE than programming.